# Selenium Webdriver.remote returns SessionNotCreatedException when trying to start a chrome session using selenium grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, selenium4

Im using selenium server 4.12.1 with chrome v117
Every time i run my python script to start a session, nothing happens for two minutes, and then it times out with a http 500 error and a SessionNotCreatedException

Im running the standalone hub on system A, and the script on system B (pointed at the system A Hub)

Ive started the Hub as follows - java -jar selenium-server-4.12.1.jar standalone --selenium-manager true.

this is my python code

```
import logging
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import random
import pytest
#import unittest

logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')

hub1_url = "http://172.16.25.86:4444/wd/hub"



chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.set_capability("browserVersion", "117")
chrome_options.set_capability("platformName", "Windows 10")

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor=hub1_url,
    options=chrome_options)


driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.quit()
```

if i run this, the following error occurs after 5 minutes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jamieb\Documents\ACC_AutoUsers\Setup.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jamieb\Documents\ACC_AutoUsers\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Jamieb\Documents\ACC_AutoUsers\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jamieb\Documents\ACC_AutoUsers\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Jamieb\Documents\ACC_AutoUsers\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not start a new session. New session request timed out 
Host info: host: 'STNUC5', ip: '172.16.25.86'
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_381'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue.addToQueue (LocalNewSessionQueue.java:224)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.NewSessionQueue.lambda$new$0 (NewSessionQueue.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle (Route.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:345)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.NewSessionQueue.execute (NewSessionQueue.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute (SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute (Filter.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:345)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute (Router.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.CheckOriginHeader.lambda$apply$0 (CheckOriginHeader.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.CheckContentTypeHeader.lambda$apply$0 (CheckContentTypeHeader.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.lambda$apply$0 (EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.java:34)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute (Filter.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:345)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$NestedRoute.handle (Route.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:345)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:345)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:345)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:345)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0 (AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0 (ErrorFilter.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute (Filter.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0 (ErrorFilter.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute (Filter.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0 (SeleniumHandler.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (None:-1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

could selenium-manager be downloading the wrong chromedriver?